# $ is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, windows, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to develop my own app using Android Studio and Google Calendar API.

The Google page says this:

> In your working directory, run the following commands:
>
> ```
> $ gradle init --type basic
> $ mkdir -p src/main/java src/main/resources
> ```

When I try to put that into the command line, it comes back with:

> '$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Am I putting this in the wrong place?

---

I didn't even realize they were assuming that people are using Linux. I have a Windows machine. I have tried all the suggestions and am not getting anywhere so far, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: This is just a convention documentation writers use.  Some shells, when they are waiting for a command, will show `$` on the screen (the _prompt_).  So if you type `gradle init --type basic`, you will see `$ gradle init --type basic` on the screen.  Documentation writers use this as a convention to say "this is a shell command" as opposed to some other types of commands.  But they don't mean to type in the `$`.  Other shells use `%` or `>` as a prompt, or part of the prompt, so sometimes I see documentation with those symbols; if you see that, you're not supposed to type in `%` or `>` either.

Comment: By the way, the shells that display `$` are Unix/Linux shells or variants.  The error message looks like a Windows error message, so most likely you're seeing a different prompt.  It's a bit sloppy of the writers to assume you're using Linux, but it's something you have to get used to.

Answer (score 2):

Not a problem at all! The $ means the following command needs to be run in the terminal (in this case, a Bash terminal). So try opening one on your machine and cd'ing into the project. Then run this:

```
gradle init --type basic && mkdir -p src/main/java src/main/resources
```

EDIT: Changed it to make use of the `&&` operator

Comment: Okay, no need to actually use two lines.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is shorthand in documentation for your command prompt and the lines mean you've got two things to enter at subsequent prompts:

1. `gradle init --type basic` and
2. `mkdir -p src/main/java src/main/resources`